# HTML form that generates next field upon completion of the previous field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create a form that displays the next section only upon proper completion of the previous one. How would I utilize back and next buttons to do this? If I press next, it would change the display setting, but would theoretically render the previous section un-editable. If I press a back button, wouldn't it recreate the previous section, thus wiping out all entries?

For reference, I'm attempting to make a better version of this buzzfeed quiz format. https://www.buzzfeed.com/abigailmcintosh/are-you-a-person-who-doesnt-like-people?utm_term=.dtdp11zkRV#.car5EEoG2q

Thank you.

Comment: can you share what you have tried? You are asking a very broad question.

Comment: What kind of 'back' and 'next' buttons are you referring to?